# knitr::knit2pdf [Error in loadNamespace(name) : there is no package called 'tinytex' Calls]

Tags: r, knitr, tinytex

I am trying to create fully portable environment = MiKTeX + TeXmaker + R-Portable + RStudioPortable + gnuplot...
In TeXmaker I created some User Commands:
[PdfLaTeX+shell]

```
pdflatex -synctex=1 -shell-escape -enable-write18 -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex
```

This works with documents containing gnuplot commands. Next objective is to create command for knitr...
[knitr]

```
Rscript -e "knitr::knit2pdf('%.Rnw')"
```

When I run it then the following Error will appear:

```
Process started

processing file: knitr-minimal.Rnw

output file: knitr-minimal.tex

Error in loadNamespace(name) : there is no package called 'tinytex' Calls: <Anonymous> ... tryCatch -> tryCatchList -> tryCatchOne -> <Anonymous> Execution halted

Process exited with error(s)
```

So it creates intermediate .tex file, but doesn't create pdf...
When I create and run command

```
Rscript -e "knitr::knit('%.Rnw')"
```

it produces .tex file without any errors

```
Process started

processing file: knitr-minimal.Rnw

output file: knitr-minimal.tex

Process exited normally
```

and than it is sufficient to run Quick Build (or PdfLaTeX) button and pdf is created...
Am I doing something wrong with knitr::knit2pdf command, or my whole portable LaTeX environment has some flaw?
p.s.: Package tinytex is not part of MiKTeX distribution...

Comment: Have you tried going into R or the RStudio Console and `install.packages("tinytex")` first?

Comment: Thank You, this was THE problem... I have installed knitr in RStudio but I was not aware of the fact that tinytex belongs to R...

Answer (score 2):

Install tinytext package using install.packages("tinytex") and try again